# emmeans for estimates from GAMs for plotting and inference in R

Tags: r, mixed-models, gam, mgcv, emmeans

I would like to be able to acquire overall estimates from GAMs of the type provided by `emmeans`, in order to plot these fitted values and their confidence intervals, and then do some subsequent analysis.

I am working on a similar dataset to the one described here: https://rpubs.com/bbolker/ratgrowthcurves . I see at the end of the document the author notes that how best to get out overall estimates from the model is not resolved, but that one option might be `emmeans`. So here I am posting an example to see if people think this approach is correct, or if they could suggest a better package and method.

I will use the 'Orange' dataset as an example, but to make it fit my question let's first add a 'variety' factor:

```
data(Orange)
temp<-as.vector(1:31)
temp[c(8:14,22:28)]<-"Tall"
temp[c(1:7,15:21,29:35)]<-"Short"
Orange$variety<-as.factor(temp)

head(Orange)

#  Tree  age circumference variety
#1    1  118            30   Short
#2    1  484            58   Short
#3    1  664            87   Short
#4    1 1004           115   Short
#5    1 1231           120   Short
#6    1 1372           142   Short
```

Create a GAM with 'variety' as a factor and 'tree' as a random effect:

```
library(mgcv)
ex.mod<-gam(circumference~s(age,k=7,by=variety)+s(Tree,bs="re")+variety,method="REML",data=Orange)
```

The ggeffects package seems to provide nice functionality for a plot via emmeans:

```
library(ggeffects)
library(emmeans)
plotme<-ggemmeans(ex.mod,terms=c("age","variety"))
plot(plotme)
```

[image: ggeffects with GAM]

Next I can extract the estimated marginal means themselves, for example over a range of ages:

```
emmeans(ex.mod,specs=c("age","variety"),at=list(age=seq(from=300,to=1500,by=500)))


#  age variety emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#  300 Short     44.8 4.37 27.1     35.9     53.8
#  800 Short     90.4 3.27 27.1     83.7     97.1
# 1300 Short    136.0 3.68 27.1    128.5    143.6
#  300 Tall      51.5 6.24 27.1     38.7     64.3
#  800 Tall     127.3 6.09 27.1    114.8    139.8
# 1300 Tall     189.8 5.56 27.1    178.4    201.2

#Results are averaged over the levels of: Tree 
#Confidence level used: 0.95
```

My questions are:

1) If I am interested in using this GAM model to e.g. comparing the estimated mean difference between orange trees of variety 'Tall' and variety 'Short' at 800 days of age, is it appropriate to base this pairwise comparison on the emmeans?

2) If several studies have been done on Orange tree growth in different places, and I am interested in meta-analysing the mean difference in circumference between 'Tall' and 'Short' variety trees at certain ages, is it appropriate to use mean differences and variance in the emmeans for meta-analysis?
(emmeans provides the SE, I think this would need to be converted to standard deviation...)

3) ... or does someone have a better suggestion for either of the above?

Comment: Have also just noticed the line for the 'Short' variety in the plot looks suspiciously straight. Have I done something wrong in the GAM?

Comment: @1 Yes,you can use pairwise comparisons from emmeans to compare the "groups" (i.e. estimated marginal means at different values), to adjust for multiplicity.@2 I'm not 100% certain, but I would say if you have comparable estimates or if you can convert your different effect sizes to a common scale, then yes. @your comment: the plot seems ok - just look at `plot(ex.mod)`, which also gives you an (almost?) straight line for the one term.